# Automatically replacing ampersand with %26

Tags: url, parameters

I am pulling data from a mysql database and using some of that data as url parameters. I'm using php to code.  My problem is that some of the company names have an "&" in them, and that causes an error when clicking on the link.  What is the best way to solve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example:

Companies
Stevens Market
Bills Hardware
T & R Homegoods

Owners
Mark
Ray
Andy

markets.php?owner="Mark"&company="Stevens%20Market" - WORKS
markets.php?owner="Ray"&company="Bills%20Hardware" - WORKS
markets.php?owner="Andy"&company="T%20&%20R%20Homegoods" - DOESN'T WORK

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Thanks, CBroe.  That did the trick!!!